# How to handle an event raised in one channel in a different channel in Hyperledger Composer of Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have this scenario that a single node is part of different channels. In one channel there are only traders. In the other channel there are traders and regulator. Details of the trades should not be shared with the regulator. The only thing which is being shared is aggregated value at the end of the business day. By aggregated value, we mean how much of each asset is sold, not the detail of each trade. In other words there is confidential information between two parties that cannot be shared with regulator, and there is aggregated value that is not confidential and must be shared with the regulator.

Now I have an event when there is a nomination. By nomination I mean a trade made over some asset in the first channel, the one without regulator. Is it possible to handle this trading event in the other channel where the regulator is?

As I read through the documents, channels are isolated. But how isolated are they? Are they isolated in a way that events raised in one channel cannot be seen or handled in another channel? In that case, how do you suggest to implement this scenario? I mean do you suggest any specific architecture or tools enabling implementation of this scenario? Also do you think Hyperledger Fabric or Composer are suitable for these requirements?

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two channels, two separate ledgers  and two separate business networks (as you've configured it).

Your 'nomination' is, in effect, a 'transaction' as described above. (events in Composer mean, business events that are usually subscribed to by a client application FYI).

In Hyperledger Composer, you can do 'cross-channel' or 'inter business network' queries. So can allow [only] the Regulator (from the 2nd channel)  to query [only] those trade 'events' (ie transactions with the fields that contain the 'trade') or indeed assets (updated by the transaction), if need be - back in the '1st' channel (and access controls) in the 2nd channel can restrict the Regulator to do only that 'query' (if that's all he/she is supposed to have jurisdiction to do). Hope this helps.

See example
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/invoke-composer-network

Comment: That was very helpful Paul, thanks. If I understood correctly you mean I add the regulator to first channel and through ACL I restrict its access. But is there a way to do so without having the regulator be part of those channels?

Comment: What I am not sure is how safe ACL is? If the node has a local copy of the ledger, how ACL is enforced? And since privacy is the most important nonfunctional requirement in this POC, I can't risk using ACL.